Existence of an inner product compatible with two decompositions of a vector space.
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Then, given a decomposition $V = A \oplus B$, any inner product such that $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal is of the form $g = g_A \oplus g_B$ with a metric $g_A$ on $A$ and a metric $g_B$ on $B$.
Now, suppose we have a second decomposition $V = C \oplus D$. When do there exist inner products $g_A$ and $g_B$ such that $C$ and $D$ are orthogonal?
Note such a inner product doesn't always exist. For example if $C \subseteq A$, we must have $B \subseteq D$.

Your question is written a bit unclearly, but I think that I now understand what you're asking. I think that you're asking the following: "Suppose that we are given two decompositions of $V$, $V = A \oplus B$ and $V = C \oplus D$. Under what conditions do there exist inner products $g_A$ over $A$ and $g_B$ over $B$ such that the spaces $C$ and $D$ are orthogonal relative to the induced inner product $g = g_A \oplus g_B$ over $V$?" Did I understand your question correctly?

Yes, that is precisely what I meant.

Isn't the condition that the induced metrics $g_A \oplus g_B$ and $g_C \oplus g_D$ are related by a transformation of the form $g_C \oplus g_D = U g_A \oplus g_B U^T$ where $U$ is an orthogonal transformation and $U^T$ denotes the transpose?

@TedBlack I don't think that you even need the orthogonal transformations. I'd say this is more a rephrasing of the question. Another way of asking the above question is: when do we have metrics $g_A, g_B, g_C, g_D$ such that $g_A \oplus g_B = g_C \oplus g_D$ as metrics on $V$.

Can you give an example of $g_A \oplus g_B=g_C \oplus g_D$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

@TedBlack Take any metric $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^4$ and two arbitrary subspace $V$, $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Then, $g|V \oplus g|{V^\perp} = g|W \oplus g|{W^\perp}$ and we also have a converse in the sense that any time $A, B, C$ and $D$ are such that the metrics $g_A, g_B, g_C$ and $g_D$ exist, they must be of this form.

OK Then my question is: since in your example $B=A^\perp$, $D=C^\perp$ and $g_A = g|{A}$, $g_B=g|{A^\perp}$ etc. how can you even define $(g|{A}\oplus g|{A^\perp})|_{C}$?

@TedBlack We always have that $g|A \oplus g|{A^\perp} = g$. Note that since $A$ and $A^\perp$ are orthogonal, choosing a basis respecting this decomposition gives us $g = \begin{pmatrix} g_A & 0 \ 0 & g_{A^\perp} \end{pmatrix}$.

Apologies my comments lack clarity. I was asking whether $(g|_A)|C$ and $(g|{A^\perp})|_C$ are defined.

@TedBlack Those would not be defined, indeed.

The following reframing of the question might be helpful: given two complementary sets of mutually orthogonal rank-1 projections, when is there a convex combination of all these that yields a block-diagonal matrix?

I must admit that I don't see why this description is equivalent. Are we fixing a metric and then picking an orthonormal basis of the decomposition $A \oplus B$. Do these then give us our rank-1 projections? I don't see why having a convex combination of these being a block diagonal matrixs would be the same as the original question.

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.
It's interesting to consider the case where $A$ and $B$ are the $x$ and $y$ axes respectively within $\Bbb R^2$ and $C,D$ are one-dimensional subspaces. Let $\mathbf c = (c_1,c_2)$ and $\mathbf d = (d_1,d_2)$ denote spanning vectors for $C$ and $D$ respectively.
The cases where either vector has a zero entry can be addressed using your statement regarding $C \subseteq A$. If $\mathbf c$ and $\mathbf d$ have non-zero entries, howevever, then suitable $g_A$ and $g_B$ exist if and only if $\frac{c_2}{d_1}$ and $\frac{c_1}{d_2}$ have opposite signs, which is equivalent to the statement that $c_2d_1$ and $c_1 d_2$ have opposite signs, which is equivalent to the statement that $c_1c_2d_1d_2 < 0$.
Geometrically, this means that one of the two vectors must be in quadrant I or quadrant III while the other vector is in quadrant II or quadrant IIII.
